# wget for recursive download of dxf files

Tags: wget, recursive

There is a web server with many dxf type files which can only be downloaded one at a time. I thought it should be a good idea to use wget to download all of those files at the same time. Unfortunately, I cannot get wget to do it successfully.

My code is:

```
wget -r -A.dxf www.site.com/example/download
```

This code gives the following error:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
Remote file does not exist -- broken link!!!
```

In case I specify the URL with exact file name

```
wget -O www.site.com/example/download/filename.dxf
```

the file downloads successfully.

How should the code look like for successfull recursive dxf file type download?

Answer (score 1):

The `403 forbidden` likely happens because the web-server forbids directory listings of the directory (thus it will not generate a file list for you).
If you know the list of files you want to download, you can create a simple text file, then tell `wget` to download the list.

Example:

```
$ cat list.txt 
file1.dxf
file2.dxf
fileA.dxf

$ wget --base http://www.site.com/example/download --input-file list.txt
```

Will download the URLs:

- http://www.site.com/example/download/file1.dxf
- http://www.site.com/example/download/file2.dxf
- http://www.site.com/example/download/fileA.dxf

Comment: Ok, this helps if a site contains only a download folder. What if download folder has subfolders which names one cannot identify in advance? Does the 403 error mean that wget will not reach those subfolders unless I specify them in URL?

Answer (score 1):

*Given that you know the filenames, they are in sequence and the webserver  lets you download in a single session *, you have a chance to get this working with shell expansion.

Suppose in your example that the filenames are file1.dxf, file2.dxf ... file5.dxf.

you can download the files as follows:

```
wget -r -np -nd http://www.site.com/example/download/file{1..5}.dxf
```

Files downloaded will be:

- file1.dxf
- file2.dxf
- file3.dxf
- file4.dxf
- file5.dxf

Similarly, if your files are filea.dxf, fileb.dxf .... filef.dxf

```
wget -r -np -nd http://www.site.com/example/download/file{a..f}.dxf
```

Files downloaded will be:

- filea.dxf
- fileb.dxf
- filec.dxf
- filed.dxf
- filee.dxf
- filef.dxf

-r: recursive, -np: no-parent, -nd: no-directories, which means that the files are downloaded but the directory hierarchy isn't.